# Is there a way to hot reload react code inside cordova?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova, hot-reload

I'm on a project that uses cordova for ios and android and we use React web app to make it show on the mobile side.

Right now, process of viewing change in the code is to compile the react code and remove the app on simulator/emulator and reinstall by opening Xcode and Android studio.

This process is hugely time consuming so I want to know if this is the only process or is there a process like react native (hot reloading when we change code).

I've researched about this and wasn't able to find any solution for this - other cordova hot reloading feature requires only change in www folder inside ios and android.
But as mentioned, in our process, to update www folder, we have to recompile everytime.

Is there a way to hot reload just by updating react code instead of recompiling?